# How to valid model state after altering the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, modelstate

I am trying to use `ModelState.IsValid` which at the moment is always comeing back false because one field in the model is empty in an object.

What i want to do is remove this object within this method and then try to `ModelState.IsValid` on the altered model?

```
loyaltyOffers = model.Offers.Where(m => m.Reward == "").ToList();
foreach (Offer offer in Offers)
{
   model.Offers.Remove(offer);
}       
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are done altering the model, use this:

```
if (TryValidateModel(model))
    // Valid!!!
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356143%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just remove the error from the ModelState:

```
ModelState.Remove("key");
```

Where "key" is the key for the error in the invalid model.